# MS SQL SP - Working with EXEC recordset

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, exec, recordset

Is there a way to work on a recordset returned from an exec within another SP? The whole recordset, preferably not using OUTPUT

I.E.

MyStoredProcedure
    @var1 int
AS
BEGIN

EXEC anotherSP @var1

-- do something against the recordset returned by anotherSP

END

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE PROC MyStoredProcedure
    @var1 int
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE #temp (
col1 ...
)

INSERT #temp
EXEC anotherSP @var1

-- do something against #temp

END
```

A table variable also wokrs in SQL 2005 and above. temp tables only for SQL 2000.